# parse json text only returned from php response in javascript/ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I am creating a website in which , I am inserting data into database using ajax XMLHttpRequest().
From php file I am sending response like this.

```
$response = array();
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
```

In javascript file I am getting response as.

```
var json = xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Now while executing, var json contains response with some additional texts
    {"success":1}< !--first comments --> < script> an script from server < /script>< !--second comments -->

**I want to parse only json text {"success":1}  using javascript, plz don't suggest jquery approach.**

I tried var obj = JSON.parse(json);, but it did not work.

Comment: after your echo ends echo json_encode($response); add 
exit;

Comment: thanks it worked , now php file returns only  {"success":1} .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ajax code to this

```
$response = array();
$response["success"] = 1;
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```